# Background worker is updating model in UI thread without issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm using a BackgroundWorker and ive implemented ProgressChanged method which gives me e.UserState to pass to my UI, which works OK.

As an experiment I changed my DoWork Method to work on the same model that is bound to the UI ListView (which is an Observable Collection)

The UI updates when I do this, & im wondering why it manages to do it flawlessly after many tests?

Im going back to using the e.UserState object but im wondering if it is normal behaviour & whats the potential problems?

Comment: First of all: what are you using as a GUI framework? I remember, for example, WinForms being exceptionally forgiving when called by a non-ui thread, and other frameworks having checks for code to use Invoke* instead of direct calls

Comment: I'm assuming the ObservableCollection is bound directly to your View?

Comment: Hey sorry I forget WPF tag, will add it now

Comment: @dema80 Funny, I always have to use Invoke using WinForms. I though WPF was forgiving in that area.

Comment: @Bob yes its bound direct

Comment: WPF automatically marshals property changes to the UI thread. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/590609/863564

Comment: @Maarten WPF is "forgiving" if you use it correctly (i.e. if you let it do the marshaling itself); some part of Winforms just had no control on the current thread, IIRC (as a rule, it should not work...)

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321423/does-wpf-databinding-marshall-changes-to-the-ui-thread. 
As long as you just change properties in your model, WPF will automatically reflect changes in the UI using the correct dispatcher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly change your *model's* properties from a background thread without any trouble; the binding engine will determine what changes need to be made to UI elements and invoke those on the dispatcher thread¹. This is normal and will not result in problems.

What you cannot (and never could) do is directly change properties of UI elements from the same background thread.

---

¹This has always been possible, and in fact it couldn't be any other way. Consider that some code (e.g. a model) needs to change a property on another model. This code surely cannot know that the property has been bound to any control, much less which control that is. Therefore it would not only be inconvenient but also horribly difficult to marshal the property change off to the appropriate UI thread each time.

Comment: He's using an `ObservableCollection`, does the UI change even if he's editing items in the collection? I don't think `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` triggers if the collection isn't adding/removing items.

Comment: Wow data binding really does have its virtue's. I get it now, model update form thread OK, UI update from thread - use ProgressChanged. Thankyou

Comment: @TinoMclaren: There are a few gotchas here though -- what changes are you making exactly? Sample code?

Comment: @Jon I cant post the code right now but its properties like ProgressBar.Value which is in a LstView. Just reading up on marshaling, what gotchas am I to look out for?

Comment: @TinoMclaren: Stuff like that (directly changing values) will always work, the binding engine does what it has to. However, you cannot do the same with things like `observableCollection.Add(stuff)` (not a property access, which is a strong hint that things are different).